# css not working on anchor tag while inside asp.net contentplaceholder

Tags: css, asp.net, class, anchor

As the title says css won't apply to my anchor tag. It does work, however, if I add the style inline, external does not work.
The anchor tag is in an aspx file that has a master page, so the anchor tag is in a contentplaceholder.
Weirdly enough the css works as normal for all the other elements that are nested inside the anchor tag.
[image: aspx code]

[image: css]

[image: master page]

Any ideas what might be causing the problem?

I tried at 'runat="server"'. I tried being more specific with the css selector. I tried selecting the anchor tag through id, class and through the parent element. None of which had any success.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As mentioned, css won't apply to my anchor tag.
More specifically, I want to apply the css to the anchor tag with the "item" class. But it won't take any css.